# Custom ConfigurationSection default boolean values

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a custom configuration section with the following property:

```
private const string UseMediaServerKey = "useMediaServer";
[ConfigurationProperty(UseMediaServerKey, IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = false)]
public bool UseMediaServer
{
    get { return bool.Parse(this[UseMediaServerKey] as string); }
    set { this[UseMediaServerKey] = value; }
}
```

My understanding is that if the property is not defined in the configuration file then the `DefaultValue` should be returned.

However, in the above case a `ArgumentNullException` is thrown at `bool.Parse(...)` meaning the default accessor is executed even when the configuration property is not defined.

Of course I could change the property accessor to:

```
    private const string UseMediaServerKey = "useMediaServer";
    [ConfigurationProperty(UseMediaServerKey, IsRequired = false)]
    public bool UseMediaServer
    {
        get {
            bool result;
            if (bool.TryParse(this[UseMediaServerKey] as string, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }

            return false;
        }
        set { this[UseMediaServerKey] = value; }
    }
```

But then, what's the point of the `DefaultValue` property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this[UseMediaServerKey] as string` is `null` because the value is of type `bool`, not `string`. You don't have to do any string conversion in a custom configuration section: everything is handled for you by the framework.

Simplify your code to:

```
public bool UseMediaServer
{
    get { return (bool) this[UseMediaServerKey]; }
    set { this[UseMediaServerKey] = value; }
}
```

And you're done. `this[UserMediaServerKey]` will return the `DefaultValue` correctly typed if there is none in the configuration file. If you ever had to change the string conversion process, put a `TypeConverterAttribute` on the configuration property. But that isn't necessary here.